# Unexpected endless loop appears

Tags: java, loops

I've got an ArrayList filled with 500 Point-Objects. There might be duplicates in it so I want to find them and if needed delete them except for one. The plan is: Check for each Point in the arrayList, if there is an equal Point, if so, add it to a List, after the test for each Point, delete all Points from the original List that are also in the toRemove-List.

But here comes the Problem: If i run this, its going for an endless loop. Do I have a serious thinking error? I think it might be a really simple misstake but I cant think about it

Also, if you have any proposal on how to do this better, let me know.

This is my method:

```
private void checkForDuplicates() {

    ArrayList <Point> toRemove=new ArrayList<Point>();
    int i=0;    
    while(i<points.size()) {    
        Point local=points.get(i);

        for (Point p: points) {
            if (local!=p && local.equals(p)) {
                 toRemove.add(p);
            }
        }

        for (Point p: toRemove) {
            points.remove(p);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Update:

Something is really broken. It looks like the method might work right now, but my programm isnt. The code isnt running anymore if I call this method somewhere. I cant even print out something on the console as the first line in my main method while i call `checkForDuplicates()` somewhere else?!

Point:

```
public class Point {

private int x;
private int y;

public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object p) {
    if (this == p) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(p instanceof Point)) {
        return false;
    }
    Point point = (Point) p;
    return this.getX() == point.getX() && this.getY() == point.getY();
}
```

}

Comment: Where is points? and which loop is endless?

Comment: Maybe you should empty ```toRemove``` after removing the points, now all the old points you already removed stay in there. Also, this will skip some of the points, since ```i``` doesn't get adjusted for the points that you remove.

Comment: points is a field (ArrayList).

Comment: I don't think it's endless but it's very slow. I think that code is `O(n^4)`. You should use a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with emptying the `toRemove` list. I think I somehow messed up my whole project because its not even running the first line of the main method for some reason, even tho i only worked in this specific method and ebfore it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Frank Puffer has answered the question in Java 8. It seems as if you're in older version of Java, so the following might help you. It just creates a Set object and copies the ArrayList to it. Because the Set will remove the duplicates automatically you don't need to make the code much more complexer than it should be, and is less error prone.

```
private void removeDuplicates() {
    Set<Point> distinctPoints = new HashSet<>();
    for (Point p : points) {
        distinctPoints.add(p);
    }
    points = new ArrayList<String>(distinctPoints);
}
```

And include the following method impl to the **Point** class so that Point objects can be searched in the Set:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hashValue = 11;
    hashValue = 31 * hashValue + x;
    hashValue = 31 * hashValue + y;
    return hashValue;
    }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point[" + X + ", " + Y + "]";
}
```

The **toString()** method is a nice to have feature.

Comment: `main.points=(ArrayList<Point>) main.removeDuplicates();`  Would this be ok if I call the method like this? I have tried it but it doesnt seem to work, there are still 500 Elements in the List even tho there should be some duplicates

Comment: @Master1114 I modified the method  (return type **void**) and removed the return statement. This is equivalent to your original code.

Comment: I understand the idea behind this, but it doesnt work for me. After running that method, the list still contains 500 objects. Also, there seems to be another problem because when I put in 3 times the same list, i get slightly different results

Comment: Nevermind. I assume due to the convertion from the set to the list, the elements have a new order each time wich is kind of a problem because I need the same result each time I run it... and there is still the first problem that it doesnt really seem to remove any duplicates

Comment: If the duplicates don't get removed, I would check the implementation of the `equals()` method. Elements in a set do not have a specific order; if order matters you can use `LinkedHashSet`instead of `HashSet`. If you want, post the implementation of the`Point`class so that I can check too.

Comment: And check the `hashCode()` implementation too.

Comment: @Master1114 I edited the answer by including a possible implementation  for `hashCode()` method.

Comment: Its working now. Thank you very much for helping out a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using streams for this task:

```
List result =
    points
    .stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

To make `distinct()` work as expected, you will probably have to define an `equals()`method for your `Point` class.

Comment: I havent heard about this so far because I am only in the first years of CS studying. But thanks for the tipp I will take a look on that.